# Accessing .Text & .Content of multiple controls within a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, properties, typeof

I've created a fairly simple `UserControl` consisting of a `TextBox` and `ComboBox`.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">        
    <MyNamespace:MultiBox Style="{StaticResource PhoneBoxStyle}" BoxType="Phone" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="phoneNumber" Margin="50,0,5,5" MinWidth="250"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=phoneNumber, Path=Height}" MinWidth="100" Name="callResultsSelection" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource callResults}}" Margin="0,0,5,5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I need to be able to then export the `.Text` & `.SelectedItem` values of those with the press of a single button.  I tried using a property like below, but it doesn't seem to work.  It does expose a `.Text` property through IntelliSense for the control, but it doesn't copy anything to the clipboard as intended.

**Original (and desired) approach:**

```
public string Text
    {
        get { return phoneNumber.Text + " - " + callResultsSelection.SelectedItem + "\r\n"; }
        set { value = phoneNumber.Text + " - " + callResultsSelection.SelectedItem + "\r\n"; }
    }
```

**Fallback approach:**

```
public string Text
    {
        get { return phoneNumber.Text; }
        set { value = phoneNumber.Text; }
    }        

    public string ComboBoxSelection
    {
        get { return callResultsSelection.SelectedItem.ToString(); }
        set { value = callResultsSelection.SelectedItem.ToString(); }
    }
```

The control iteration I'm using is as follows.  There are a lot more of these sections, but this is the only relevant one.

```
foreach (object o in ccChildren.GetChildren(tool, 3))
            {
                if (o.GetType() == typeof(CallTemplate))
                {
                    CallTemplate template = (CallTemplate)o;
                    if (template.Text != null)
                    {
                        textBuffer += template.Text;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textBuffer = "";
                    }
                    tempString += textBuffer;
                    textBuffer = "";
                }
            }
```

By using breakpoints, I do know that it does reach the decision point in the `if` block, but even though VS recognizes the `CallTemplate` object, it doesn't match it.  Anyone see the problem?

**Edit:**  I do know that the problem is not with the iteration method (ccChildren.GetChildren).  I am using this with a multitude of other controls (textbox, combobox, radio button, checkbox) and it works perfectly fine.  The only thing in that area that could be an issue is the `CallTemplate` type.

Comment: In property .Text @ set{} you should use value, not assign it!

Comment: else
{
     textBuffer = "";
}
seems wrong?!

Comment: I switched value to the other side of the equal sign, no effect.  As for textBuffer = "", the controls it's iteration through are a series of labels and textboxes.  Before the if-block, the label is added to textBuffer.  But if the control the label refers to is empty, the label needs to not be added to tempString so there are no blank lines.

Comment: When you debug is this true or false
(template.Text != null)

Comment: Just checked again, and it's neither.  It seems that the problem must be in it checking the type, as it never manages to make it inside that if-block.  But how can that be if even VS if recognizing it as a valid type?

Comment: you dont need set part in the property only get is enough.To where you want to import the property value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this would be one of those moments of sheer stupidity.  My only problem was that I hadn't added the GroupBox containing the UserControl to the array of GroupBoxes to iterate through.  Thanks for the helpful replies though...

Answer (score 0):

this is user control xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="phoneNumber" Margin="50,0,5,5" MinWidth="250"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=phoneNumber, Path=Height}" MinWidth="100" Name="callResultsSelection" ItemsSource="{Binding stud}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="0,0,5,5"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

This is codebehind of usercontrol

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            stud = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
            stud.Add(new Student() { Name = " chauhan", RollNo = 1212, About = "dc wecwedc wec cwec wevcwe vcwd vcwvc" });
            stud.Add(new Student() { Name = " chauhan", RollNo = 1212, About = "dc wecwedc wec cwec wevcwe vcwd vcwvc" });
            stud.Add(new Student() { Name = "chauhan", RollNo = 1212, About = "dc wecwedc wec cwec wevcwe vcwd vcwvc" });
            stud.Add(new Student() { Name = " chauhan", RollNo = 1212, About = "dc wecwedc wec cwec wevcwe vcwd vcwvc" });
            stud.Add(new Student() { Name = "chauhan", RollNo = 1212, About = "dc wecwedc wec cwec wevcwe vcwd vcwvc" });
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Student> stud
        { get; set; }
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return phoneNumber.Text + " - " + callResultsSelection.SelectedItem + "\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int RollNo { get; set; }
        public string About { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is window xaml where above usercontrol is used

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <uc:UserControl1 Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ucw"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And below is code behind of window

```
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {    
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ucw.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Here when i click button the Text property of usercontrol is giving correct value in the message box. Hope this will help.